# on form submit using ajax and getting value from php function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form calling submitting as follow

```
<form action="" method="post" id="member_form" onsubmit="return json_add('member','<?php echo ($admin->getnew_id()); ?>','0','slider_form');">
```

The problem I have is to get the $new_id before submitting the form from another function class.
this is not working 
It keep running the funtion getnew_id() and generate the ID before it is saved
I need the process as follow.

1. Form Open
2. User complete form
3. onsubmit  it need to do follow.
   a. get new id = $new_d
   b. then do

   return json_add('member','','0','slider_form');">

I tried the following but dont work

```
$("form").submit(function(){

    $.ajax({
            url:"lastid.php",
            type:'POST',
            success:function(response) {
                var $new_id = $.trim(response);
                return json_add('member-add',$new_id,'0','slider_form');
                alert("Submitted");
            }


});
```

Comment: You need to do part 3 in several steps, so your classical "return" strategy won't work.  One of those steps is sending a request to the server.  Another is receiving and handling the response.  The second step is all done inside the success function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the third step.

What you should do is prevent the form from submitting and handle it in ajax.

1. you need `onsubmit="return false"` to prevent the form from submitting
2. Next, handle the submission in ajax

   ```
   $("form#member_form").submit(function(){
     $.ajax({
           url: "lastid.php",
           type: "POST",
           data: {   // this is where your form's datas are
               "json": json_add('member-add',$new_id,'0','slider_form'),
               "key": $("form#member_form").serialize()
           },
           success: function(response) {
               var $new_id = $.trim(response);
               alert("Submitted");
               // alerting here makes more sense
           }

     // return json_add('member-add',$new_id,'0','slider_form');
     // returning here do nothing!
   });
   ```

You can read more about using ajax in jQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Hi I made a mistake. the return json_add should only take place on success. i have edited and made the changes